# How to create a custom button and use multiple times in best way in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, button

I have created a custom `UIButton` in ios. I want to use the same custom button ten times with the same attributes but different titles. What is the most efficient and clever way to do this without repeating the same code for each button? Should it be a struct or a class or something else? How can I implement it? Attributes that I have changed for my custom button is as follows:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var button_1: UIButton!

 button_1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, button_1.frame.width, button_1.frame.height)
 button_1.clipsToBounds = true
 button_1.layer.cornerRadius = button_1.frame.width/2.0
 button_1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
 button_1.layer.borderWidth=2.0
```

Comment: both answers worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create your own class that extends from `UIButton`

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
final class CoyoteButton: UIButton {

    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 2.0
    var borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    @IBInspectable var titleText: String? {
        didSet {
            self.setTitle(titleText, for: .normal)
            self.setTitleColor(UIColor.black,for: .normal)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2.0
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}
```

To set a text to the button, just write `myButton.titleText = "myText"`.

Then you can drag and drop a `UIButton` from the interface builder and then change the class of that button to your own `MyOwnButton`, or create one by code.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This code works just the way I want expect it does not display the title of the button. Although I have given a title for each button in the storyboard, it is not showing. I have tired adding self.setTitle("myTitle", .Normal) etc. in the above code but still doesn't work.

Comment: Check the modified answer. You can set the button title using the 'titleText' property.

Comment: Add super.layoutSubviews() in layoutSubviews(), then you can see text!

Answer (score 6):

You need to create the `extension` of `UIButton` like this

```
extension UIButton {
    class func attributedButton(frame: CGRect) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(frame: frame)
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button_1.frame.width/2.0
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        return button 
    }
}
```

Now call this method like this way

```
let button = UIButton.attributedButton(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 10, 40)
button.setTitle("Title", forState: .Normal)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Now you can use this method every time you want to create a button with these fixed attributes.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Should be the selected answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

question author marked correct answer (author: Brigadier), but it not works properly in swift 4 (maybe in other versions to, have not checked).
For example when I set button title it is not shown in run time. the reason is following: it is not called super.layoutSubviews().

The correct way is here:

```
@IBDesignable
class MyOwnButton: UIButton {
     var borderWidth = 2.0
     var boderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
     @IBInspectable
     var titleText: String? {
          didSet {
             self.setTitle(titleText, forState: .Normal)
             self.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
         }
     }   

     override init(frame: CGRect){
         super.init(frame: frame)
     }

     required init?(aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         super.init(aDecoder: aDecoder)
     }

     override func layoutSubviews() {
         super.layoutSubviews()
         setup()
     } 

     func setup() {
         self.clipsToBounds = true
         self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2.0
         self.layer.borderColor = borderColor
         self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a [repo](https://github.com/titopalito/CustomUIButton) with a custom button.

You could use it: https://github.com/titopalito/CustomUIButton

It is not mine, I got it from a tutorial ;)

Best regards.